# gnome-terminal: cursor blinks in inactive window

Tags: debian, gnome-terminal, lxde

I am using `gnome-terminal` in LXDE. When I have several `gnome-terminal` windows open, after some time the cursor in the inactive window starts to blink as well, as if the inactive window was actually active.

This only happens with `gnome-terminal`. Other terminal emulators such as `LXTerminal` work fine.

see video of the problem here: http://youtu.be/nRBehoJ1L7Y

I am aware of this [bug](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2013-February/035333.html). But this should have been fixed in my version of xserver-xorg-core 1.12.4-6. I am using Debian Wheezy and gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1-2

I am wondering if this could be caused because I am using `gnome-terminal` on LXDE. Could there be some gnome component missing? I have no way of testing if the same problem exists on Gnome.

Comment: Is this causing you a problem? If it is there may be other solutions. Also LXDE is a desktop environment; do you mean to say that your window manager is Openbox?

Comment: (I *can* at least tell you that it does not happen with gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1 running on X 1.11.4 with compiz 0.9.7.12, fwiw.)

Comment: This problem is driving me crazy. I have two monitors, each with a maximized window of `gnome-terminal`. Now I cannot distinguish which terminal is active, so often I start typing only to realize that I am typing into the other terminal window. Then I have to activate the desired window with a mouseclick, or alt-tab. For reasons beyond this discussion, I must use `gnome-terminal` (it has a functionality which no other terminal emulator has). And yes, my window manager is Openbox.

Comment: You can just move to [Terminator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_U2Yy5B2ASU#t=13)

Comment: It is a bit ugly in the beginning, but you can easily customize to look like `gnome-terminal` and use its great features

Comment: sorry, but this will not do. I must use `gnome-terminal` because of its color palette. AFAIK, no other terminal emulator has the feature I need.

Comment: `terminator` provides lots of color schemes (I think they are the same as `gnome-terminal`, not sure), if any of then did not suit your needs, you can easily create a new one in the Preferences/Profiles/Colors

Comment: You are correct. `terminator` indeed has the same color palette as `gnome-terminal`. I'll check it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to `terminator`.

It is an [awesome](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_U2Yy5B2ASU#t=13) full featured terminal emulator. It is a bit ugly (in my opinion) when you install, but can easily customize it and even made it look like `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-terminal developers are aware of the issue, it is reported at
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=947847

Since it's hard to reproduce, it's quite hopeless to start debugging it.  Any help, especially a way to reproduce it frequently would be highly appreciated.  Please comment on that bug if you can offer any help.

Comment: It turned out to be caused by https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677329 which just got fixed recently.